# Ionic build apk android

Tags: android, build, ionic-framework, apk

I'm trying to build an apk from my ionic project.
When I launch ionic build android, i get this error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
  >   Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:support-v13:23+
  >   .
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v13/maven-me
  >   tadata.xml
  >        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v13/
  >    Required by:
  >        :android:unspecified
  >   Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-service
  >   s-gcm:+.
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >            //repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-gcm
  >   /maven-metadata.xml

BUILD FAILED

What is it?

Comment: There might be permission problems.By running command sudo ionic run android will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an error related to `android tools version`.By executing the following commands will resolve your issue.

```
android list sdk
```

and

```
android update sdk --no-ui --filter extra
```